# How to create authentication using an external text file

Tags: python, authentication, text-files

As part of a larger program, I need to check someone's username and password against a external txt file.

Do I need to use a dictionary inside my text file or something?

```
username = input("What is your username?")
password = input("Password?")

#To do: check username + password against external file users.txt
#users.txt is in the same directory as the program
```

Comment: These aren't plaintext passwords are they?

Comment: This is a school project, so encryption isn't really required.

Comment: Also, all solvers - I'm still learning Python so please don't skip too many steps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your passwords aren't encrypted, you can directly read the file, and split it to have the different users and passwords in a dictionary.

For example, if your file is formatted for each line a user and a password, separated by a space, you can use a program like this:

```
username = "username"
password = "password"

with open("users.txt", "r") as passwordsfile:
    passwordSeparator = " "
    # One line format, you can use one of the following solutions
    passwords = {
        x.split(passwordSeparator)[0]: x.split(passwordSeparator)[
            1
        ]  # x should be in "username password" format, so we have to split it
        for x in filter(
            None, passwordsfile.read().split("\n")
        )  # The filter function remove the empty lines
    }

    # Multiline solution:
    passwords = {}
    separatedLines = filter(None, passwordsfile.read().split("\n"))
    for x in separatedLines:
        _username = x.split(passwordSeparator)[0]
        _password = x.split(passwordSeparator)[1]
        passwords[_username] = _password


# print(passwords) : {"user1": "password1", "user2": "password2"}

# Check the user and password with assert
try:
    assert (
        passwords[username] == password
    )  # assert is useful to check a condition in our program. This is useful in a try/except bracket, because in this case, we have no guarentee that the username is in the password database
    print("You're logged in")
except:
    print("Wrong password or username!")
```

However, if you have a large user database, you should have a look at database storage (SQLite, MySQL, ...) for performance, and you may have to encrypt your user's passwords.

Comment: Tried this, has the following error code:
 _line 14, in <module>
    passwords = {x.split(" ")[0]: x.split(" ")[1] for x in filter(None, passwordsfile.read().split("\n"))}
  File "filename", line 14, in <dictcomp>
    passwords = {x.split(" ")[0]: x.split(" ")[1] for x in filter(None, passwordsfile.read().split("\n"))}
IndexError: list index out of range_

Comment: Sorry if this is terribly formatted, first SO post.

Comment: username password. Should it be comma separated or something?

Comment: Well, this should work with spaces, but your error tells that one line is not correctly formatted, as the x variable can't be split. (I updated my code to make a bit clearer).

Comment: Done! Thanks so much, this will really help.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I got from your Question is that you want to 
Creating a login/Authentication program that recalls information from text files,

```
def main():    
username, password = get_name_and_password()  
registered_users = read_pwdfile('pwd_filename')  
if usr_pass_registered(username, password, registered_users):  
    registered = True  
else:  
    registered = get_registration(username, password, 'pwd_filename')  
if registered:  
    print(You are logged in)
```

#You need to save your username and password in csv format(comma separated)

Comment: "NoneType object is not iterable."